# Realm 1.0.1 iOS obj-c compilation error

Tags: realm, realm-migration, realm-cocoa

I updated my Realm for iOS Obj-C from 0.98 to 1.0.1
but now we're getting these error during compilation:

> undef: __ZN5realm4util23PlatformSpecificCondVarC1Ev undef:
>   __ZN5realm4util23PlatformSpecificCondVarD1Ev undef: __ZNK5realm13TableViewBase16maximum_datetimeEmPm undef: __ZNK5realm5Table16maximum_datetimeEmPm undef: __ZNK5realm11StringIndex3getEmRNSt3__15arrayIcLm8EEE undef: __ZN5realm5Table12set_datetimeEmmNS_8DateTimeE undef: __ZN5realm9Allocator10do_reallocEmPKcmm undef: __ZNK5realm5Table16minimum_datetimeEmPm undef: __ZN5realm5QueryC1ERKNS_5TableERKNS_4util8bind_ptrINS_8LinkViewEEE undef: __ZNK5realm13TableViewBase16minimum_datetimeEmPm undef:
>   __ZNK5realm5Table12get_datetimeEmm undef: __ZN5realm14LinkListColumn19unregister_linkviewERKNS_8LinkViewE Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "realm::util::PlatformSpecificCondVar::PlatformSpecificCondVar()",
>   referenced from:
>         realm::SharedGroup::SharedGroup(realm::Replication&, realm::SharedGroup::DurabilityLevel, char const*, bool) in
>   libRealm.a(shared_realm.o)
>   "realm::util::PlatformSpecificCondVar::~PlatformSpecificCondVar()",
>   referenced from:
>         realm::SharedGroup::SharedGroup(realm::Replication&, realm::SharedGroup::DurabilityLevel, char const*, bool) in
>   libRealm.a(shared_realm.o)
>   "realm::TableViewBase::maximum_datetime(unsigned long, unsigned long*)
>   const", referenced from:
>         auto realm::Results::max(unsigned long)::$_3::operator()(realm::TableView const&)
>   const in libRealm.a(results.o)
>   "realm::Table::maximum_datetime(unsigned long, unsigned long*) const",
>   referenced from:
>         auto realm::Results::max(unsigned long)::$_3::operator()(realm::Table const&) const in
>   libRealm.a(results.o)   "realm::StringIndex::get(unsigned long,
>   std::__1::array&) const", referenced from:
>         void realm::StringIndex::set(unsigned long, realm::null) in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o)
>         void realm::StringIndex::erase(unsigned long, bool) in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o)
>         void realm::StringIndex::erase(unsigned long, bool) in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o)
>         void realm::StringIndex::erase(unsigned long, bool) in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o)
>         void realm::StringIndex::set(unsigned long, long long) in libRealm.a(RLMQueryUtil.o)
>   "realm::Table::set_datetime(unsigned long, unsigned long,
>   realm::DateTime)", referenced from:
>         realm::RowFuncs >::set_datetime(unsigned long, realm::DateTime) in libRealm.a(RLMAccessor.o)
>         copy_property_values(realm::Property const&, realm::Property const&, realm::Table&) in libRealm.a(object_store.o)
>   "realm::Allocator::do_realloc(unsigned long, char const*, unsigned
>   long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         vtable for realm::Allocator in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o)   "realm::Table::minimum_datetime(unsigned long, unsigned long*) const",
>   referenced from:
>         auto realm::Results::min(unsigned long)::$_7::operator()(realm::Table const&) const in
>   libRealm.a(results.o)   "realm::Query::Query(realm::Table const&,
>   realm::util::bind_ptr const&)", referenced from:
>         realm::Table::where(realm::util::bind_ptr const&) in libRealm.a(RLMArrayLinkView.o)
>   "realm::TableViewBase::minimum_datetime(unsigned long, unsigned long*)
>   const", referenced from:
>         auto realm::Results::min(unsigned long)::$_7::operator()(realm::TableView const&)
>   const in libRealm.a(results.o)   "realm::Table::get_datetime(unsigned
>   long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
>         realm::RowFuncs >::get_datetime(unsigned long) const in libRealm.a(RLMAccessor.o)
>         copy_property_values(realm::Property const&, realm::Property const&, realm::Table&) in libRealm.a(object_store.o)
>   "realm::LinkListColumn::unregister_linkview(realm::LinkView const&)",
>   referenced from:
>         realm::LinkView::~LinkView() in libRealm.a(RLMArray.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm using cocoapods to install it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more info like what version of CocoaPods you use, Xcode version?

Comment: cocoapods 1.0.0, xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downgrading the cocoapods to 0.39.0
and did this

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
pod install
```

This works for now.